# Master method algorithm analysis of pseudocode

Tags: master-theorem

How do you find the c/d constant used in the master theorem by examining this pseudo-code?

```
FastPower(a,b) :    
     if b = 1 
         return a 
     otherwise 
         c := a*a 
         ans := FastPower(c,[b/2]) 
     if b is odd 
         return a*ans 
     otherwise return ans 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need to find your recurrance relation: T(n) = a T(n/b) + O(D) + O(C) where O(D) is the time it takes to divide the problem into subproblems, O(C) is the time it takes to recombine the subproblems into the answer, a is the number of subproblems, and n/b is the size of the subproblems. Then, once you have the recurrence you can analyze using the Master Theorem.

In your algorithm, I believe there is one subproblem of size n/2, so a is 1 and b is 2. The time for dividing is O(1) and time for recombining is O(1) assuming the analysis is not in terms of bit operations.

Using the master theorem, O(1) = Θ(n<sup>log<sub>2</sub>1</sup>) so therefore the total runtime is Θ(n<sup>log<sub>2</sub>1</sup> log n) = Θ(log n)